# WebSocket Error on Android Device, Works in IE

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile, websocket

I have an issue with a websocket client.

It seems to work fine in IE and Edge. The server responds with a message and the client receives and displays this message, but when my android device runs this code, the error handler gets fired off and the connection is closed immediately.

The error handler gives me a message: "undefined"

Here is my Client:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML5 Touch Tracing </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

      function openSocket(){
                
            if ("WebSocket" in window)
            {
               alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
               
               //var WebSocket = require('ws');
               var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/WebSocketServer/control");
               
                            ws.onopen = function ()
                            {
                                // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
                                ws.send("Message to send");
                                alert("Message is sent...");
                            };

                            ws.onmessage = function (evt)
                            {
                                var received_msg = evt.data;
                                
                                alert("Message = " + received_msg);
                            };

                            ws.onclose = function ()
                            {
                                // websocket is closed.
                                alert("Connection is closed...");
                            };
       ws.onerror = function(evt)
       {
        alert("Error: " + evt.data);
       };
            } else
            {
                alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
            }
   

                
  }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no">
   
   
   <div>
    <a href="javascript:openSocket();" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" id="button">Keyboard</a>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My Server simply just responds with a message:

```
@OnMessage
public String onMessage(String message) {
    return "Got it.";
}
```

Comment: Maybe because you are connecting to localhost?

Comment: omg i think that actually might be the problem. I will test it out later since im at work. I didnt realize i hardcoded localhost into the websocket client. I need to put the ip of the server and it *should* work.